# Garbage collection and object initializer

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test { Name = "One" };
        var test2 = new Test { Name = "Two" };
        var weak = new WeakReference<TestRef>(new TestRef(test, test2));
        var weak2 = new WeakReference<TestRef>(new TestRef(test) { Test2 = test2 });
        GC.Collect();

        TestRef tref;
        TestRef tref2;
        var @is = weak.TryGetTarget(out tref); //FALSE
        var @is2 = weak2.TryGetTarget(out tref2); //TRUE
    }
}

class Test
{
    public Test()
    { }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class TestRef
{
    public TestRef(Test test)
    { Test = test; }

    public TestRef(Test test, Test test2)
    {
        Test = test;
        Test2 = test2;
    }
    public Test Test { get; set; }
    public Test Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

In this example if object was *initialized with constructor* after **GC collection** object will be *removed* from the heap, **but** *with object initializer* the reference will be *alive* after **collection**.
Why `@is == false` and `@is2 == true`?
Why `weak2` still has object after `GC.Collect()` but `weak` does not?

Comment: I have a short answer: the only question I've found here is whether anyone has a short answer. Please read my comment again.

Comment: do you have a question? :P

Comment: Sorry, the question is:
Why `@is == false` and `@is2 == true`?

Comment: That was clear before, but why then object not removed from the heap?

Comment: Even if I do this `var weak2 = new WeakReference<TestRef>(new TestRef(new Test()) { Test2 = new Test() });` it is still alive! Why? It does not have any strong reference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" occurs because you are making assumptions about the behavior of the garbage collector which are not mandated by the C# language specification. In particular, you assumed that each of the objects you passed to the `WeakReference` constructor would be eligible for garbage collection on the next line. This is not a correct assumption; in fact, the C# compiler will actually produce two different behaviors depending on whether or not you've enabled optimizations, and neither is more correct than the other.

**Note:** The following evaluation was performed using the Roslyn CTP for Visual Studio 2013 and [ILSpy 2.2.0.1706](http://ilspy.net/).

### Optimize Code Disabled

With optimizations enabled, the intermediate value is actually stored in a temporary local variable created especially for it. The particular line is the `IL_0042: stloc.s 9` line, which stores the object in local variable `[9]`. This variable is not set to `null` after it's used, so the reference actually prevents the object from getting garbage collected until the `Main` method returns.

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 112 (0x70)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class Test test,
        [1] class Test test2,
        [2] class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef> weak,
        [3] class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef> weak2,
        [4] class TestRef tref,
        [5] class TestRef tref2,
        [6] bool is,
        [7] bool is2,
        [8] class Test,
        [9] class TestRef
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void Test::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.s 8
    IL_0008: ldloc.s 8
    IL_000a: ldstr "One"
    IL_000f: callvirt instance void Test::set_Name(string)
    IL_0014: nop
    IL_0015: ldloc.s 8
    IL_0017: stloc.0
    IL_0018: newobj instance void Test::.ctor()
    IL_001d: stloc.s 8
    IL_001f: ldloc.s 8
    IL_0021: ldstr "Two"
    IL_0026: callvirt instance void Test::set_Name(string)
    IL_002b: nop
    IL_002c: ldloc.s 8
    IL_002e: stloc.1
    IL_002f: ldloc.0
    IL_0030: ldloc.1
    IL_0031: newobj instance void TestRef::.ctor(class Test, class Test)
    IL_0036: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef>::.ctor(!0)
    IL_003b: stloc.2
    IL_003c: ldloc.0
    IL_003d: newobj instance void TestRef::.ctor(class Test)
    IL_0042: stloc.s 9
    IL_0044: ldloc.s 9
    IL_0046: ldloc.1
    IL_0047: callvirt instance void TestRef::set_Test2(class Test)
    IL_004c: nop
    IL_004d: ldloc.s 9
    IL_004f: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef>::.ctor(!0)
    IL_0054: stloc.3
    IL_0055: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
    IL_005a: nop
    IL_005b: ldloc.2
    IL_005c: ldloca.s tref
    IL_005e: callvirt instance bool class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef>::TryGetTarget(!0&)
    IL_0063: stloc.s is
    IL_0065: ldloc.3
    IL_0066: ldloca.s tref2
    IL_0068: callvirt instance bool class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef>::TryGetTarget(!0&)
    IL_006d: stloc.s is2
    IL_006f: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

### Optimize Code Enabled

With optimizations enabled, you can see that the intermediate value is only stored on the stack; no `stloc` instruction is used to place it in a local variable. The functionality has been more efficiently provided by the `dup` instruction on line `IL_0033` instead. When this code is run, the garbage collector will most likely be able to collect the object because it is no longer part of the thread's stack at the time `GC.Collect` is invoked.

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 86 (0x56)
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] class Test test2,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef> weak,
        [2] class TestRef tref,
        [3] class TestRef tref2
    )

    IL_0000: newobj instance void Test::.ctor()
    IL_0005: dup
    IL_0006: ldstr "One"
    IL_000b: callvirt instance void Test::set_Name(string)
    IL_0010: newobj instance void Test::.ctor()
    IL_0015: dup
    IL_0016: ldstr "Two"
    IL_001b: callvirt instance void Test::set_Name(string)
    IL_0020: stloc.0
    IL_0021: dup
    IL_0022: ldloc.0
    IL_0023: newobj instance void TestRef::.ctor(class Test, class Test)
    IL_0028: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef>::.ctor(!0)
    IL_002d: stloc.1
    IL_002e: newobj instance void TestRef::.ctor(class Test)
    IL_0033: dup
    IL_0034: ldloc.0
    IL_0035: callvirt instance void TestRef::set_Test2(class Test)
    IL_003a: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef>::.ctor(!0)
    IL_003f: call void [mscorlib]System.GC::Collect()
    IL_0044: ldloc.1
    IL_0045: ldloca.s tref
    IL_0047: callvirt instance bool class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef>::TryGetTarget(!0&)
    IL_004c: pop
    IL_004d: ldloca.s tref2
    IL_004f: callvirt instance bool class [mscorlib]System.WeakReference`1<class TestRef>::TryGetTarget(!0&)
    IL_0054: pop
    IL_0055: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```